# Regex update for email field

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that works fine for checking an email format in my code.

```
^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

This is been working fine for a long time in our code.
Now they changed the requirements and are asking us to make a change so that the email field does not accept two periods (..) consecutively.

I tried to change it and it didn't work properly. How can the above regex changed so that it wont accept two periods consecutively?

Comment: Add `(?!.*?\.\.)` after `^`

Comment: Email regexes are such a sad waste of time. This one blocks many completely valid email addresses while it allows invalid host names...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you. your suggestion worked!